# randomize default products in opencart

Tags: random, opencart, product

I'm using OpenCart V1.5.3.1 and am trying to randomize or shuffle the products per category on page load.
The other sort options should still work though (per price, rating, alphabetical,..).

Anybody that can give me some pointers?

Many thanks,
Steven

Code I've tried:
In controller/catalog/product/category.php

Just below

`$this->data['products'][] = array(
                    'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
                    'thumb'       => $image,
                    'name'        => $result['name'],
                    'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, 100) . '..',
                    'price'       => $price,
                    'special'     => $special,
                    'tax'         => $tax,
                    'rating'      => $result['rating'],
                    'reviews'     => sprintf($this->language->get('text_reviews'), (int)$result['reviews']),
                    'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&product_id=' . $result['product_id'])
                );`

I added:

```
shuffle($this->data['products']);
```

In stead of this I also tried this:
Just below:

```
$results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($data);
```

I added:

```
        srand((float)microtime() * 1000000);
    shuffle($results);
    $results = array_slice($results, 0, $data['limit']);
```

Both these methods unfortunately shuffle also the results when choosing another sorting option (rating, pricing, name). I only want the initial results on page load to be shuffled.

Comment: Please include some code to show
[what you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Sorry Serge, I edited my initial post with more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution:

Go to `catalog/model/catalog/product.php` and find the method `getProducts($data)`.
Here change this:

```
if (isset($data['sort']) && in_array($data['sort'], $sort_data)) {
    if ($data['sort'] == 'pd.name' || $data['sort'] == 'p.model') {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY LCASE(" . $data['sort'] . ")";
    } else {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY " . $data['sort'];
    }
} else {
    $sql .= " ORDER BY p.sort_order";   
}
```

to this:

```
if (isset($data['sort']) && in_array($data['sort'], $sort_data)) {
    if ($data['sort'] == 'pd.name' || $data['sort'] == 'p.model') {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY LCASE(" . $data['sort'] . ")";
    } else {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY " . $data['sort'];
    }
} else {
    $sql .= " ORDER BY RAND()"; 
}
```

(hint: only the last `$sql .= ...` changed)

By this simple change if there is no sorting chosen the products will always be sorted in random order.

Comment: Many thanks shadyyx. However, this also causes the other frontend sorting methods being randomized, like A-Z and low>high pricing etc.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit to quick with my comment. I needed to undo my previous mods obviously. However, replacing the $sql line doesn't seem to have any influence. So the products are default still loading alphabetically.

Comment: @Steven_B Probably You had changed also anything else that You didn't revert back... With no changes in controller and no other changes in model this should make the products order in a random order if no other order method is choosed by user...

Comment: Thanks shadyxx, it does seem to work now (I uploaded the original product.php files to be sure. Do you also know how to have the products shuffled with each page load? Now it seems to randomize and then stays in that order. Nothing important, just curious :-)

Comment: @Steven_B That is because products are cached to speed up the page load. If You would like to randomize on each pageload, then comment out these caching lines: `$product_data = $this->cache->get...` (line 35) - should be enough, but You could also comment out line 164 `$this->cache->set...`.

Comment: Now I bumped onto another side effect of RAND(). It interferes with the products loaded on the next product pages. It seems to RAND() the total products list again when you go to the next page, so some are shown in multiple pages, some not shown at all. An idea to overcome this? (I didn't comment out the cashing lines)

Comment: Hi, this was quite predictable...It could be overcome but it requires more modifications to the Product model and the method `getProducts()`. Just an algorithm: You would have to check for the `$data` variable and whether You asked for the first page or not. **If the first page of products was required, just use SQL query with RANDOM and cache the result**. Otherwise (another page than first was required) get the products from cache and filter out those for the second page. Could be quite easy to implement. Huh?

Comment: Many thanks @shadyyx! I'll do some experiments with SQL queries. It's all a bit new to me but slowly but surely I'll get the hang of it :-)