# Opencart sort by newest product

Tags: php, opencart

The question is kind of similar to [randomize default products in opencart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659495/randomize-default-products-in-opencart), but simpler. I am trying to have my products listed by newest first. I made the following change in `catalog/model/catalog/product.php`:

```php
if (isset($data['sort']) && in_array($data['sort'], $sort_data)) {
    if ($data['sort'] == 'pd.name' || $data['sort'] == 'p.model') {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY LCASE(" . $data['sort'] . ")";
    } else {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY " . $data['sort'];
    }
} else {
    $sql .= " ORDER BY p.date_added";
}
```

But I don't see this having any effect to the default sort.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of OC do You have, but You should also consider modifying the *order* part. In OC 1.5.5 it is like this:

```
    if (isset($data['order']) && ($data['order'] == 'DESC')) {
        $sql .= " DESC, LCASE(pd.name) DESC";
    } else {
        $sql .= " ASC, LCASE(pd.name) ASC";
    }
```

In this case, with Your change and if no sort nor order data is provided the products will be sorted from the oldest to newest (oldest first). I recommend changing the *order* part to something like this:

```
    if (isset($data['order']) && ($data['order'] == 'ASC')) {
        $sql .= " ASC, LCASE(pd.name) ASC";
    } else {
        $sql .= " DESC, LCASE(pd.name) DESC";
    }
```

If You are saying that there is no change also try to delete Your browser session as the sorting, filtering and other options are stored there.